# Automated Testing performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout doesn't work from command line ?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Im writing automated tests for iOS using UIAutomation. In my setup code (javascript) I use the performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout method to call the "curl" command to hit a URL.

`target.host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("usr/bin/curl", ["http://TEST123/iPhoneTestSupport/Data/RemoveAllData"], 30);`

This works fine in the tests when I run the tests manually through the Instruments UI, however this doesn't work when I run the tests through the Instruments command line. The error I get is "launch path not accessible". The user running through the command line as the same one as through the UI.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the starting forward slash from the path. This was causing the error. I changed it to the code below and this resolved the issue.

```
target.host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/curl", ["http://TEST123/iPhoneTestSupport/Data/RemoveAllData"], 30);
```

Comment: huhu, in which of the code should i give the http method and the content for a POST?